# Geta data from DB by EntityFramework by TPC strategy

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I use EF6 in my project. I have abstract class "Animal" and two class, which inherit by it: Cat and Dog.

As inherit strategy I want to use TPC (table per concrete), my DbContext look like below

```
public class AnimalDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Cats");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Dogs");
        });
    }
}
```

This code create proper tables in my database. My question is how can I read data from Cat or Dog table? In my AninamDbContext object I don't have Cats or Dogs property.

```
using (var db = new AnimalDbContext)
{
    //how can I there read from db I cats?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the following?

```
using (var db = new AnimalDbContext)
{
    var cats = db.Animals.OfType<Cat>().ToArray();

    // Or when you want to get animals of multiple types
    var catsAndDogs = db.Animals.Where(a => a is Cat|| a is Dog).ToArray();
}
```